# JMSSerializer Expected end of input, but got "/" of type T_NONE

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization, jmsserializerbundle

i'm using JMS for serialize and deserialize my entities i have a batch process to generate a json file and other read that file

my entity has a field DateTime like the following

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="inscription_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 * @JMS\Type("DateTime<'d/m/Y'>")
 */
private $inscriptionDate;
```

when the entity is serialized the result is

```
"inscription_date":"30\/05\/2007"
```

but the problem is when i'm going to deserialize i get

```
[JMS\Parser\SyntaxErrorException]                                            
Expected end of input, but got "/" of type T_NONE at position 11 (0-based).
```

**Note**: when i use the `json_decode` built-in function return a stdClass without problem

---

#### Update 1

not appear to be this field, I deleted the field of the original serialization, and yet still get the same error. each object is serialized in a single line, each separated by a PHP_EOL

this is a sample of the data `people.json`

```
{"name":"dexter","date":"13/04/2009", "doc": "1047516320" }
{"name":"deedee","date":"30/05/2013", "doc": "1047516325" }
```

all fields are valid and data types are numbers or strings

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when de-serialization fails. Make sure that you pass correct json with correct types of data. Also check if your sub-objects that also will be de-serialized also are correct - passed json also must be correct.

Also make sure to write your class correctly without forward slash:

```
@Type("Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\City")
```

Also make sure that this is actually class, but not interface (you probably need to write interface resolver to implement that)

Comment: This actually helped me to solve the problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The parser is choking on invalid JSON in people.json.  The forward slash, or solidus, needs to be escaped.  See JSON documentation here http://json.org/ and read the section on strings.

Your source JSON should look like this:

```
{"name":"dexter","date":"13\/04\/2009", "doc": "1047516320" }
```

If you have no control over the source JSON, then you must write your own Handler implementing SubscribingHandlerInterface and register it with your serializer.